# Open a .toast file in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, images

I have a .toast file.

How do I open it in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the application [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html). Another possibility is to use [ToastMount](http://toastmount.sourceforge.net/). And i think Disk Utility (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility) or the default Disk Image Helper App can handle the images, too (try double clicking!).